# Web scraping ilegal?

Tags: discusión

Oficialmente el scraping no es legal, sin un consentimiento previo de las partes.

Lo avala la ley Española y Europea.

No se debería permitir preguntas sobre este tema en este sitio.

Links de referencia:

https://pi22.eu/index.php/zona-clientes/legislacion/lopd-y-gdd-lopdgdd-3-2018-5d-de-proteccion-de-datos-personales-y-garantia-de-los-derechos-digitales/114-lopd-y-gdd-lopdgdd-3-2018-titulo-ix-regimen-sancionador/516-lopd-y-gdd-lopdgdd-3-2018-articulo-72-infracciones-consideradas-muy-graves

https://pi22.eu/index.php/zona-clientes/legislacion/lopd-y-gdd-lopdgdd-3-2018-5d-de-proteccion-de-datos-personales-y-garantia-de-los-derechos-digitales/114-lopd-y-gdd-lopdgdd-3-2018-titulo-ix-regimen-sancionador/518-lopd-y-gdd-lopdgdd-3-2018-articulo-74-infracciones-consideradas-leves

https://gdpr.algolia.com/es/gdpr-article-45

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿ Se rechazan todas, o solo cuando el OP es de España ? ¿ En que nos basamos para saber su localización ?

Comment: Yo lo haria todas las preguntas relacionadas con el tema, ya que es Stackoveflow España no?

Comment: Por un lado, el scraping no es ilegal per se. Si los datos no son de caracter personal, o protegidos por copyright, o incluso si el scraping se hace para uso personal, puede ser valido. Por otro, como bien dice @trauma, hablas de normativas europeas que pueden no ser de aplicación en otros paises. Y, por ultimo, he leido el articulo 45 varias veces y no me queda claro en que parte se habla del web scraping. Podrías aclararlo?

Comment: @Pikoh, hago unas capturas y lo pongo, a mi personalmente, me da lo mismo, solo quiero advertir, que esto es sancionable, a nivel empresarial y personal. Experiencia propia.

Comment: Como ya te dije, me parece bien que informes de que hacer web scraping **podría** ser ilegal. Pero no nos corresponde a nosotros decidir si una pregunta sobre este tema hace referencia a una actividad legal o no. Imagina que tengo el consentimiento de la otra parte. Podría hacer una pregunta sobre el tema en ese caso?

Comment: Y si fueran tarjetas de crédito? seria lo mismo? tus datos son iguales de peligrosos que una tarjeta de crédito existe la suplantación de identidad.

Comment: Los enlaces aportados hablan de vulneración de la ley de protección de datos personales, pero no del _scraping_ como técnica. Entiendo que hacer _scraping_ de páginas web que ofrecen información pública y de caracter no personal (por ejemplo, conversión de divisas, precios de productos, etc.) no quedan amparados por esa ley.

Comment: @Srsole Esto es StackOverflow **en español** (con minúscula y todo). Seguramente haya mas usuarios de Hispanoamérica que de España.

Comment: Ostias, no me habia fijado nunca que pone en español, siempre habia leido mentalmente "España"

Answer (score 10):

Hay muchas prácticas que podrían ser ilegales en ciertos escenarios, quizá incluso en casi todos los que se aplican, pero no dejan de requerir ciertos conocimientos de sistemas y programación que puede ser bueno conocer.

Ejemplos:

- Estudiantes de seguridad requerirán herramientas de "*pentesting*" (de *penetration testing*, pruebas de penetración en sistemas) cuyo uso fuera de auditorías de seguridad será totalmente ilegal.
- El *web scrapping* puede ser realizado para obtener información pública de distintos medios públicos para unificarla ([*web mashup*](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mashup_(aplicaci%C3%B3n_web_h%C3%ADbrida))), en cuyo caso, a menos que los servicios explorados prohíban en sus EULAs el uso de scrappers, no debería haber problemas legales.

En mi opinión es sano conocer estas tecnologías/técnicas tanto como para reconocerlas cuando las usan contra nosotros como para poder encontrar usos legalmente aceptables. En SO y SOes he visto preguntas cerradas porque van claramente en contra de la ley o son inmorales (hacking de cuentas, pirateo de software privativo...), pero son tan pocas que creo que se pueden valorar individualmente en lugar de cerrar todas "por decreto"

Comment: Totalmente de acuerdo, incluso a programación como herramienta puede usarse para programar un marcapaso o para hackearlo y detenerlo.